# Why click event don`t work when re-append element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why click event not work in this code (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3WeP5/):

```
var holder = $("<div></div>");

$(document.body).append(holder);

var btn = $("<button>Click Here</button>");

btn.click(function(){alert('clicked');});

holder.append(btn);
holder.html("");
holder.append(btn);
```

you can replace this line:

```
btn.click(function(){alert('clicked');});
```

with (Not work again):

```
btn.bind("click",function(){alert('clicked');});
```

and if i dont use jquery and set javascript event like this, it works fine!!

```
btn[0].onclick=function(){alert('clicked');}
```

**Why click event don`t work when i re-append element (button) and how can i fix it?**

Comment: use `btn.on('click', function(){});`

Comment: @ Spirals Whirls Check it http://jsfiddle.net/3WeP5/2/ not work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look the [documentation of `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
>   Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.

`holder.html("");` is removing the handler of the button. If you want to keep it you can use `clone` as:

```
holder.append(btn.clone(true));
holder.html("");
holder.append(btn.clone(true));
```

Comment: +1 For explaining why. If only more people would read the documentation.

Comment: @FelixKling << If only more people would read documentation. >> you would have less work here :)

Comment: Tanx, I gave you upvote and i accepted your answer for explanation and i saw amazing answers here from Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui and Connor, tanx guys!

Answer (score 3):

Try `on` [jQuery ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
// You are better off just adding a id to the button

var btn = $("<button id=\"someButton\">Click Here</button>");

$(document).on('click', '#someButton', function(){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

What this does is add's a click listener to the document and when someone click's the document it checks to see if the `event.target === btn`

Here is a demo

The reason that the event's don't work is because `jQuery.html();` removes the event listeners it is confirmed here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L231

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WeP5/6/)

Comment: Woh Woh Woh! 3 Seconds Difference  LOL :P

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui but this answer doesn't use delegation, which why it is wrong

Comment: Yeah, i didn't think you could use event delegation on elements like that, i thought you had to provide a class || id, but iv'e just tried it in a fiddle so ill change it now.

Comment: @Connor You are right and so your code is still wrong, you have to use string selector for delegation, not DOM element or jquery one. As here 'btn' is a jquery object, you could use btn.selector but it is deprecated

Comment: Maybe this only works with jQuery Objects and not DOM elements

Comment: @Connor i saw jsfiddle .. sorry i write wrong code.. its ok, i give you and upvote

Comment: This also doesn't answer *why*, which was the question.

Comment: @Connor your code is just setting click to document, check your jsfiddle, you can click anywhere in the page, event is fired. As here btn is not a string, the parameter 'btn' passed to handler is ignored and so 'compiled' as: `$(document).on('click',function(){});`

Comment: @Connor No, here it is the body which fired the event, still not the btn. Just click near the right of the button and see event fired (in your jsfiddle, using the code you posted here would work using string #someButton). See the doc for on(), only a string selector is available

Comment: yeah. i know forgive me, the body is only as high as the button thats why i got confused

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document.body).on('click', btn, function() {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Your code doesnot work because when the script if first loaded it binds the function to that particular element but when you add another one the script doesnot run again and so the appended element doesnot get its event binded. When we add event delegation, we target `document.body` and so when the script gets loaded event gets binded to that element on the `body`.

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3WeP5/5/)

For earlier versions of jQuery you may use this one:

```
$(document.body).delegate(btn, 'click', function() {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asked *why* the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: The OP is not adding a *new* element, they are adding the same element they already bound the event handler to. Your explanation does not fit the situation here.

Comment: @Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui i saw, yes i write wrong code.. its ok, i gave you upvote too..

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh Are you aware if you click anywhere in the body, this event is fired?

Comment: @roasted he fixed it.. tanx god.. i thought, i waste my vote..!!